# Stop looping pivot control in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to stop the loop of pivot item from the first item to the last item and opposite.

This is the change I did in the xaml:

```
 <phone:Pivot x:Name="pivot" Height="698" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,10" 
LoadingPivotItem="Pivot_LoadingPivotItem" LoadedPivotItem="Pivot_LoadedPivotItem" >
```

c#:

```
PivotItem currentItem;
private void Pivot_LoadingPivotItem(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (currentItem == firstItem && e.Item == lastItem) 
    {
        e.Item.Header = currentItem.Header;
        pivot.SelectedItem = currentItem;
    }

    if (currentItem == lastItem && e.Item == firstItem) 
    {
        e.Item.Header = currentItem.Header;
        pivot.SelectedItem = currentItem;
    }

}

private void Pivot_LoadedPivotItem(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
{
    currentItem = e.Item;
}
```

it's not working..

the problem is that the item is staying (like i want) but the header of the item isn't.

do you know why? what is the solution?

thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You really should not use pivot in thic case- it's not what it was created for. Instead you should implement it by yourself, here's a good start: [Creating a swipable ContentControl](https://forty3degrees.wordpress.com/2011/07/19/creating-a-swipable-contentcontrol/)